# Laravel Mysql Show records in view

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel, datatables

What Is the Best way To list Customer Record in laravel if I have a more then 2000 records in SQL database? I used Jquery DataTaables right now but it takes time to load.

Comment: I think it's better to use pagination. Here's the official Laravel documentation: [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)

Comment: use datatables with ajax-loaded content. I use it for a huge sets of data and it works fine

Comment: 2000 records in one page? so i suggest to use infinite scroll that will split records and is a friend of your processor and memories.

Answer (score 0):

It is best way to paginate records in model, after that your result will be returned to controller then you can pass in to view layer using blade template

```
    $page = $request->input('page');
    $users = DB::table('costumers')->paginate($page);
```

Comment: remember don't prefer to get records more than hundred at one time. always paginate these queries

Comment: Thanks I use  Laravel pagination. there is an error when viewing the record  " Call to undefined method stdClass::links()". how to solve it

Comment: i think you are not calling paginate function from a DB model. Ensure if you are using database model

Comment: you are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

if you had not changes too much in that records, you can cache all the history of the customer in cache system like Redis. if you cannot as @Bora Erbasoglu said you have to paginate through them